# How can I add entries to my Model in Django, that are linked to a user using Firebase?

Tags: django, firebase-authentication

I am using React with FireBase to create users account on my Frontend. I am creating a table to track a users weight and it appears like this,

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Units(models.TextChoices):
    KILOGRAM = 'kg', _('Kilogram')
    POUND = 'lbs', _('Pound')


class WeightTracking(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    units = models.CharField(choices=Units.choices, max_length=3)

    def _str_(self):
        return f'On {self.date}, you weighed {self.weight}{self.units}'
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to track this to a user that is logged in. How can I add an entry that is linked to a user. FireBase gives me a UID for the user which I can send to the django backend, but doesn't Django have a default id column? How can I customize it or what is the best approach to linking an entry to a user for my future queries. Thanks!